# Tensorflow installation error building a .whl file

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, bazel

While following the MacOS installation and after successfully running the .configuration script, I get an error when attempting to build the pip package.  The error in terminal shows as follows:

```
Sat Nov 25 22:47:25 EST 2017 : === Building wheel
error in tensorflow setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected ',' or end-of-list in backports.weakref >= 1.0rc1; python_version < "3.4" at ; python_version < "3.4"
```

The full error message is:

```
Laurences-MacBook-Pro-3:tensorflow qaneuro$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
Sat Nov 25 22:47:21 EST 2017 : === Using tmpdir: /var/folders/7t/77lrlr0n56z9s05dbzl42lq00000gn/T/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX.1suikQIy
~/ex5/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package.runfiles ~/ex5/tensorflow
~/ex5/tensorflow
/var/folders/7t/77lrlr0n56z9s05dbzl42lq00000gn/T/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX.1suikQIy ~/ex5/tensorflow
Sat Nov 25 22:47:25 EST 2017 : === Building wheel
error in tensorflow setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected ',' or end-of-list in backports.weakref >= 1.0rc1; python_version < "3.4" at ; python_version < "3.4"
```

Has anyone else had this problem or can provide advice on how they solved it?

Comment: what is the version of python you're using?

Comment: @UbdusSamad Python 2.7.10

Comment: I would suggest changing the default python version to python3.5 and trying again, but there are certain risks involved if you mess it up and couldn't revert it back!

Comment: In linux changing the default version of python is like saying goodbye to most of your apps (i case you can't revert it back to 2.7). But am not very sure what will happen if you do that on a  mac!

Comment: @UbdusSamad yes I was afraid of that scenario as I read this could be risky.  What if I have both python and python 3 installed?  I ask because I ran python3 --version and received Python 3.6.3.  Can I run this bazel command somehow using python3?

Comment: I am not quite sure about that, but best guess will be no! But you could use docker environment and then make python3 as default for that environment and then try installing bazel and tensorflow. Are you doing this for ML applications?

Comment: @UbdusSamad yes this is for ML, I'm interested in object detection and decided to use Tensorflow as an approach.  What made you ask?

Comment: The fact that you mentioned bazel, I had been involved in ML myself but because of lack of time, I didn't really got anywhere with it. What kind of object are we talking here?

Comment: I haven't decided how far I should break this problem down but the goal is to detect flags from different countries.  I'm guessing start with one flag and work my way away from there. @UbdusSamad

Comment: That won't be too difficult (If you have GPUs), assuming flags will have a rectangular geometry, use OpenCV to detect rectangular contours in a frame then analyze them one by one by a trained model!